# Xtext parse EMF model interface

Tags: java, parsing, xtext, emf

I am trying to parse the ecore model. If there is an interface linked field, i can't access it's implementation values.

**Xtext Grammar:**

```
Map:
  type=MapCreate
  name=ID '='
  mapcontent+=MapBody (',' mapcontent+=MapBody)* ';';

  MapCreate:
  'Map' '<' keyType=MapKeyDataType ',' valueType=MapValueType '>';

MapKeyDataType:
  'String' | 'int';

MapValueType:
  MapKeyDataType | 'float' | MapCreate;
```

**sample implementation:**

```
Map<int, String> ma = {0="a", 5="b"};
```

---

Parsing the `keyType` field works well, but how to do the same with `valueType`? It's always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar is bogus. Essentially you try to make instances of your `Map` be a super-type of instances of `String`. That will never work and Xtext will likely show some warnings for that grammar.

What happens is basically the following:

You define a rule `MapKeyDataType` as a data type rule (refer to the docs for details). That is, its return type is `String`.

Also you define a rule `MapValueType` that delegates to `MapKeyDataType`. This implies that the return type has to be assignment compatible (a super type) of the return type of `MapKeyDataType`. It would have to be a `String` or one of its super types, e.g. `Object`. Now you also delegate from `MapValueType` to `MapCreate`. `MapCreate` in turn does not produce a plain string but instances of `MapCreate`. Your `MapCreate` and Java's `String` are generally not assignment compatible. The type inference of Xtext now makes `MapKeyDataType` no longer returning String but declares the return type `MapKeyDataType` instead. There won't be any instances, though, since they are never instantiated: the parser rule does not have any assignments. That's why your grammar causes trouble on your side.

Something like this could clean that up a little bit:

```
Map:
  type = MapType name=ID '=' ...;
MapType:
  {MapType} name='Map' '<' keyType=PlainType ',' valueType=ValueType '>';
PlainType returns Type:
  name = 'String' | name='int';
ValueType returns Type:
  MapType | PlainType | ValuePlainType;
ValuePlainType returns Type:
  name='float';
```